# Distance between two Random Variables by comparing Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. Define the distance between $X$ and $Y$, $d(X, Y)$ as: $$d(X, Y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\mathbb{P}(X < t) - \mathbb{P}(Y < t)\right|dt$$
whenever this integral makes sense. Does this distance have a name? (Or, do you know of any similar constructions?) I am interested in examples for which the total variation distance is large but this distance is not so large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that, for any distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$,
$$
d(\mu,\nu)=\inf\{\mathbb E(|X-Y|)\mid \mathbb P_X=\mu,\mathbb P_Y=\nu\}.
$$
This is called the [Wasserstein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) (for the $L^1$ distance) , or the Monge-Kantorovich-Rubinstein metric, or some other name.

By comparison, the total variation distance $d_{TV}$ is defined as
$$
d_{TV}(\mu,\nu)=\inf\{\mathbb P(X\ne Y)\mid \mathbb P_X=\mu,\mathbb P_Y=\nu\}.
$$
If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on the integers, using the inequality $\mathbb 1_{x\ne y}\leqslant|x-y|$ for integers $(x,y)$, one sees that $d_{TV}\leqslant d$ (but that no inequality $d\leqslant c\cdot d_{TV}$ can be valid).

For measures on the real line, no inequality $d_{TV}\leqslant c\cdot d$ can be valid, as the example of Dirac measses at $x$ and $y$ shows, when $x-y\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am unsure whether the Wasserstein distance is equivalent to the distance I alluded to (is this what you were suggesting by "it seems that"?)

Comment: If I were you, I would try hard to show that your $d$ is indeed the Wasserstein distance.

Comment: They may be equivalent, but I don't think they are the same, as evaluating them on a uniform distribution on $[0, 1)$ and $[1, 2)$ shows.

Comment: For Uni(0,1) and Uni(1,2), one gets distance 1 with both formulas...

Comment: You're right. My error.

Comment: Ok, I believe they are the same. The main strategy of the proof being to write $\mathbb{P}(X < t) = \mathbb{E} \mathbb{1}_{X < t}$, etc., and exchange order of integration (with lots of other details).

Comment: Yep. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

In the paper ["Calculation of the Wasserstein Distance Between Probability Distributions on the Line"](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1118101), it is shown that your distance is *precisely* the [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) with $p=1$, if your space is the real line.

In particular, given two probability measures $P_X$ and $P_Y$ on $\mathbb R$ (with corresponding CDFs $F_X$ and $F_Y$), the Wasserstein metric (with $p=1$) becomes:
$$
W_1(P_X,P_Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|F_X(t)-F_Y(t)|\,dt,
$$
which is exactly your measure. The result can be extended to probability measures defined on $\mathbb R^n$.

Moreover, if your space is *bounded* in $\mathbb R$, $W_1$ metrizes *weak convergence*. That is, letting $\rightharpoonup$ denote weak convergence, we have:
$$
P_n\rightharpoonup P\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}W_1(P_n,P)=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It looks very close to what is called [the total variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures)  between two probability measures.

Comment: Total variation distance seems similar, but may be quite different. Take the example of two random variables that have disjoint, but interlaced, supports. Total variation will be as large as possible, but the distance described above will be relatively small (compared to supports that are widely separated on R).

Comment: @thethuthinnang What do you mean with "disjoint but $interlaced$" supports?

Comment: @thethuthinnang Do you mean, that the support of _each_ (or one of) random variable is disjoint but for _both of them_ they interlace? Well, this is as close as I have seen in literature (I mean the total variation distance).

Comment: I think he means something like a situation where the supports of $X$ and $Y$ are $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (2n+1,2n+2)$ and $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (2n,2n+1)$ respectively.

Comment: I mean exactly the sort of situation Rookatu describes. If you add further that X is n on (2n + 1, 2n + 2), and Y is n on (2n, 2n + 1), with the measures of those intervals being the same under the corresponding probability measures, then we have a situation where two random variables are very similar, but total variation sees them as being as different as possible.

Comment: My previous comment doesn't really make sense. In fact it is misleading to talk about the support of a random variable, as 'support' is something ascribed to the domain, and the domain of a random variable is in the probability space itself (whose construction we often don't care to know any specifics about).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any special name for that function; in any case in order to satisfy the property

$$d(X,Y)=0 \Leftrightarrow X=Y$$

one needs to consider the equivalent classes of continuous random variables which are equal in distribution. On other constructions: usually divergences are used to introduce distance-like measure of distances between random variables. You can check "Methods of Information Geometry" by Amari and Nagaoka for all constructions and definitions. If you are searching for a distance (in the pure mathematical sense), then probably you should have a look at Information Value and Hellinger distance.

Comment: This is a distance, but between *distributions*, not between random variables.

Comment: @Did: sorry, but I can not see that point; in the question it is stated that $X$, $Y$ are random variables, and the distance is $d(X,Y)$.

Comment: I know what is stated in the question (since I can read). My comment explains what *should* have been written.

Comment: @Did happy to $read$ that!

Comment: I am interested in comparing distributions, not random variables. Feel free to edit the question to reflect that. I didn't know how to word it.